# How to use sed in shell script with value containing line break \n?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, sed

In my shell script I have `conf=2bi5oIl0hldy/p3fe+KMQTVjUSg89ywhdMCaSOAopEVFM\nKlj4RDJcmNcEa1cgxL3sJNBHrw==\n`

And I have a ini file that has parameter looks like this:

`^PASS= SNlfkDahPoWNYCY0V+Z77iR8bP5GIpp8FL6GX5fBvGhfnvH\nRbtyBU06EGifzFyBvZgrqFi/Dw==\n`

('=' might have space before or after)

I need to replace what comes after ^PASS= with the $conf value including the slashes and backslashes and other characters without cutting the string off.

I have this sed expression :

`sed -i "/^[^#]/ s|\(\^PASS *= *\)[^ ]*|\1$conf|g" "file.ini"`

As a result, I get in file.ini :

`^PASS=2bi5oIl0hldy/p3fe+KMQTVjUSg89ywhdMCaSOAopEVFM`

`Klj4RDJcmNcEa1cgxL3sJNBHrw==\n`

So the conf value is breaking to new line, due to `\n` after the `M`.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the `\n`? Is it two characters a backslash and a `n` or is it a single LF character? Sed see whole lines so should not see the end-of-line (or line separation) characters.

Comment: Try `sed -i "/^[^#]/ s|\(\^PASS *= *\)[^ ]*|\1${conf//[&$'\n'|\\]/\\&}|g" file.ini`